# Casting Volumetric Shadows in Cycles Fastest Way

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics, shadowcatcher

I am experimenting with trying to combine Eevee for volumetrics and Cycles for everything else. I have found a way to produce smoke that is really effective and much more efficient than using cycles which takes a horrendously long time to render. I am using a particle emitter to emit vdb object and set to increase to full size as [per this short video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/45814t74ut3ox0n/Particles%20as%20smoke%20test%20Cycles%20%2B%20Eevee%202%200001-0250.mkv?dl=0).

As you can see, Eevee does not cast shadow. This was done combining Cycles and Eevee, but even with the Eevee only render, it is a limitation of Eevee that volumes will not cast shadows on solid objects.

Using this technique renders really fast - about 5 seconds per frame for cycles and eevee combined. But because the smoke is from the particle system, there is hundreds of vdb images of a cloud meaning easier manipulation of smoke, but cycles freaks out over that. Eevee renders almost instantly and it's good enough.

So what I thought might be possible is to use the volume to cast a shadow, meaning I could turn cycles volume rendering to its fastest least detailed settings and turn on indirect for the collection that governs the smoke emission. It works, but it's still really slow (though much faster than trying to render the smoke in cycles). 19 minutes versus 5 seconds!!

- Does anyone know of a way we can use cycles to catch the shadow of a volume without calculating the light passes of the volume?
- Is there another way to "cheat" a shadow from the volume onto hard surfaces in Eevee?

Comment: Well, since _Cycles_ somehow needs the light passes to get the shadows (I guess that's why they are not in Eevee), I don't think it will be easy to achieve. What about disabling the _Ray Visibility_ for everything except _Shadow_ in the object properties? In a simple scene I have reduced the _Cycles_ render time at 200 samples from 18.48 seconds to 8.07 seconds.

Comment: OUCH!! Sorry about that. Very embarassing. The technique worked but it doesn't look as good as in the viewport. Here is the short film: https://tinyurl.com/5e79vamt

Comment: Well, it looks like the smoke is close to the light source and therefore the shadow is very large. But without the comparison to the viewport I cannot see how good looking it is there.

Comment: You can see the shape of the cloud in the viewport version but it doesn't look like this in the render. I am going to give your Ray visibility in object properties a try. https://ibb.co/34Z51Sy

Comment: The reason the shadow looks right in view port and not in render is because the "indirect only" doesn't seem to work correctly in renders. I don't know if this is a bug or something I am not understanding. To replicate set up a volume to create shadow in a collection set to "indirect only". It looks correct in viewport but does not render.

Comment: And if you would take it out of this collection? Because my suggestion didn't need this setting.

Comment: My test work fine so far, even with _Indirect Only_. Are you sure it's the shadow that's incorrect or does it look different in the viewport because of other light paths...? Try to enable everything in the _Ray Visibility_ section except for _Camera_. Then it will still be invisible for the camera but interact normal with all other surfaces, reflections etc. But of course this will increase the render time again.

Comment: Just to confirm, your trick DOES work. It also works on volumes that being used as objects for particles. It is still not working in my first test project for some reason I still can't work out, but trying it another test project DOES work.